# Get Category of Point of Interest of iOS Maps App

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I need to obtain a list of categories to assign to a business. I noticed that when using `iOS Map`s and creating a new **point of interest**, the **Maps** app prompts us to enter a **category**, displaying a mandatory list of available categories.

I specifically need this list. Is anyone aware of how to obtain this list? Using `MapKit`, is it possible to access the list you see? I'm sharing a screenshot I took from the device using the **Maps app**.

[image]

Comment: I can't say this is the same list, since that is not in a language I speak, but the documentation makes mention of a `MKPointOfInterestCategory` - I would start pulling the thread there: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpointofinterestcategory/
And the request: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalpointsofinterestrequest

Comment: @yonodactyl I tried to work with Point of Interest but it returns a very short list of categories and it doesn't seem to be the same as the one that Apple provides on the maps app when you insert a new point of interest

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this data is coming from the Business API.

If you [check out](https://businessconnect.apple.com/docs/data-specification/v1.3/categories) their BusinessConnect API page, they give you a complete list of these categories to download as a `.csv` file.

Comment: first of all thank you very much for your help it would have been difficult to find this information.. now I wonder.. Can this category information be used without problems? also how could you get the data based on the location of the app? or how could I obtain this data in Italian?

Comment: If you mean if you can legally use the information, that I am not sure. I would check the License and terms on the API and their business site and see.

I imagine that the information is localized on their end, so maybe a little digging around on the API side of things you might be able to see if it's returned localized.